# rspec shared examples vs shared context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

What is the real difference between `shared_examples` and `shared_context` ?

My observations :

1. I can test same things using both (i.e. with `shared_examples` or `shared_context`)
2. But some of my other tests fails if I use later one.

**Observation #1 :**

I compared [shared_examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/example-groups/shared-examples) and [shared_context](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/example-groups/shared-context) per documentation on https://www.relishapp.com/

Syntactical differences are :

- shared_context to define a block that will be evaluated in the context of example groups by implicitly matching metadata

Example :

```
shared_context "shared stuff", :a => :b do
  ...
end
```

- The way these are included or called from a test file

shared_examples

```
include_examples "name"      # include the examples in the current context
it_behaves_like "name"       # include the examples in a nested context
it_should_behave_like "name" # include the examples in a nested context
```

shared_context

```
include_context "shared stuff"
```

**Observation #2**

I have a test case

```
shared_context 'limit_articles' do |factory_name|
  before do
    @account = create(:account)
  end

  it 'should restrict 3rd article' do
    create_list(factory_name, 3, account: @account)

    article4 = build(factory_name, account: @account)
    article4.should be_invalid
  end

  it 'should allow 1st article' do
    ...
  end

  it 'should allow 2nd article' do
    ...
  end
end
```

And include the context in a spec file which already has one shared_context included, then the existing one fails. But I change the order then all my test passes

*Fails*

```
include_context 'existing_shared_context'

include_context 'limit_articles'
```

Also if I replace the `shared_context` with `shared_examples` and accordingly include it in test case.

*Passes*

```
include_context 'existing_shared_context'

it_behaves_like 'limit_articles'
```

Comment: The following pages from `rspec` documentation should tell you their purposes: [`Shared examples`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/example-groups/shared-examples), [`Shared context`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/example-groups/shared-context)

Comment: I have updated my question with examples and detailed observations.

Comment: Observation 2 contains tests. It should be a shared example group. It's just about readability in your tests.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`shared_examples` are tests written in a way that you can run them in multiple settings; extracting common behavior between objects.

```
it_behaves_like "a correct object remover" do
    ...
end
```

`shared_contexts` is any setup code that you can use to prepare a test case . This allows you to include test helper methods or prepare for the tests to run.

```
include_context "has many users to begin with"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have updated my question with examples and detailed observations.

Answer (score 21):

`shared_examples` contain a collection of examples which you can include in other describe blocks.

A `shared_context` contains a collection of shared code, which you can include in your test file. Think of this like a ruby module.

You use a `shared_context` in your test code by including it with the `include_context` method.

On the other hand, you state that a certain thing `behaves_like` a shared example group.

It's a matter of readability I guess.

UPDATE:

If you look at the source code you'll see that they're exactly the same thing. Check out line 98 in this file:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/shared_example_group.rb#L98

```
alias_method :shared_context,      :shared_examples
```

You'll also see that `shared_examples_for` is another alias for the same method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand the theory but then it looks almost similar to me except few syntactical differences.
I have updated my question with examples and detailed observations.

Comment: It's simple really ... put tests into a shared example that you want multiple things to conform to. Put code into a shared context that you need to include in multiple tests.

Answer (score 5):

Very trivial and cosmetic, but `include_context` doesn't output "behaves like" in `--format documentation`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great write-up by Rudy Jahchan that not only shows how to use both `shared_context` and `shared_example`, it also shows *why* they're valuable.
It does so by taking a spec and then refactoring (DRYing) it to use `shared_example` and `shared_context`.

[BDD Composition over Inheritance with RSpec Shared Examples](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/08/07/bdd-composition-over-inheritance-with-rspec-shared-examples/)